# Why doesn't rx receive data from loopback tx on UART?

Tags: c

I have [a system](https://elinux.org/Jetson/GPIO) running Linux, connected the rx to the tx (loopback) from UART1 and executed this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int iFd = open("/dev/ttyTHS0", O_RDWR);
    if (iFd < 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error when opening file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (1) {
        if (write(iFd, "A", strlen("A")) == -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed to write\n");
            return -1;
        }

        char buff[10] = {
            0
        };

        if (read(iFd, buff, sizeof(buff)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Failed to read.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "read: %s\n", buff);

    }
    close(iFd);

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is it doesn't seem to receive any data. The code simply blocks at `read`. I can see the data being transmitted on the tx line when looking at it with an oscilloscope, but the rx doesn't receive anything. I have also tried splitting this code in 2 processes, one process for the transmission and another one for the reception, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It is logical. You probably do not send anything as it is sits in the send buffer.  Other problem is that you try to receive 10 bytes, but send only one. On many systems serial timeouts are set to infinitive time and you will wait forever for the next 9 bytes.

what to do (point 2 has some variants):

1. flush the UART file

2a. read only as many bytes as you sent
`ioctl(ifd, FIONREAD, &bytes_ready_to_read);` and then read only the number available.

2c. change the timeout.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I don't think flushing the transmission buffer will change anything because I can clearly see my data the data being sent when I measure things with an oscilloscope. I tried changing the number of bytes I read to the number of bytes being transmitted, but that didn't change anything. My code: receiver: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hKX4xdd4Mn/ , transmitter: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CS335bV7Rk/ 
I now tried to run two different processes to try to track down the issue

Comment: Adding the ioctl line you suggested, doesn't change anything neither unfortunately

Comment: Do you happen to have any other suggestions?